# how do I insert a default row?

Tags: sql-server

If I create a table with an identity column as primary key, and all the other columns have default values, for example

```
create table rr (id int identity(1,1) primary key, dt datetime default getdate())
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To insert a single row

```
INSERT INTO RR DEFAULT VALUES;
```

It is possible to insert multiple rows of default values by (ab)using `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO RR
USING (SELECT TOP 1000 *
       FROM   master..spt_values) T
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
  DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Comment: For multiple rows you could also use `GO 1000` - not exactly the same thing but much less hassle than trying to memorize that syntax. :-)

Comment: Yes, `GO 1000` seems to be much easier. Thanks for that.